# Error while using user-defined table type in sql --> Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with "user defined table type"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use a user-defined table in a stored procedure but while running my procedure im getting error as

```
 "Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with ..."
```

I have defined one user defined tabel as below:

```
CREATE TYPE [myUserTable] AS TABLE(
    [Id] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL)
```

Stored procedure:

```
Create PROCEDURE FETCHUSER
(@USERS [myUserTable] readonly,
   @Firstname varchar(max))
select * from UserTable as ut, @USERS as mt where mt.Id = ut.Id
```

While executing, I have supplied input params as:

`@USERS = 'Sample'`

but getting error as

```
"Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with ..."
```

Please help me out. Any suggestions, appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following code can help you

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[myUserTable] AS TABLE([Id] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL);

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].FETCHUSER
@USERS [myUserTable] READONLY,
@Firstname VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM   UserTable    AS ut
           JOIN @USERS  AS mt
                ON  mt.Id = ut.Id;
END
GO


DECLARE @users [myUserTable]

INSERT INTO @users
VALUES
   (
    '1'
   ) ,
   (
    '2'
   ) 

EXEC FETCHUSER @users,
     'yourFirstName'
```

Comment: Hi Reza, thankyou above code works fine. One final doubt, how to check the values present in userdefined table. For example, select * from UserTable - giving error

Comment: you're welcome. Do you want to know if the UserTable table existed?

Comment: yes also, Im passing my myUserTable values from C# code as tablevalued parameters.is this table defined type, will hold the values which we stored earlier if so how to check the values in user defined table. (like select * from myusertable --- gives error)?  --Invalid object name 'myUserTable'

Comment: you can check exist type  `myUserTable` by `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1  FROM sys.types  WHERE IS_TABLE_TYPE = 1 AND NAME = 'myUserTable') BEGIN          
        --your code
    END` if you need to check exist table you can use `IF EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
       FROM   sysobjects
       WHERE  NAME          = 'yourTableName'
              AND xtype     = 'U'
   )
BEGIN  End`

Comment: Do you want to create `myUserTable` if not exist?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a parameter value which exists. If you want to `select` from `myUserTable`, then pass that instead of `sample`. Also, you need to pass a `FirstName` of `varchar(max)` type. You will need to make sure that whatever you pass is compatible with this type. Finally, if `my.Id` and `ut.Id` are of incompatible types, then you will need to convert one of them into the other's type for the sake of comparison.

Comment: Hi Arpad,Could you please give me an example :(  Basically can we test or pass my table valued param using SP (just to test it from sql server)

Comment: @suryaok there are a lot of places which might be causes of the problem. Try creating an empty procedure with similar headers and call it. Would that be executed or not? If it would, then you pass your parameters correctly. If not, then you need to fix the way you call the stored procedure.

Comment: How to insert or select values from table defined types?

Comment: @suryaok have you conducted the experiment I have suggested you to do? If so, what was the result?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are declaring a `@USERS` variable as `varchar` whereas the expected stored procedure parameter type is `myUserTable`. To pass a table-valued parameter value, you need to declare a variable of the table type, insert rows into the table variable, and then call the proc.

Below is a refactored example based on the code in your question using modern ISO SQL join syntax. Not sure how `@FirstName` is used in your actual code but I kept it here.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FETCHUSER
    @USERS [myUserTable] readonly
   ,@Firstname varchar(max)
AS
SELECT *
FROM UserTable AS ut
JOIN @USERS AS mt ON mt.Id = ut.Id;
GO

DECLARE @myUserTable [myUserTable];
INSERT INTO @myUserTable(ID) VALUES(N'Sample');

EXEC FETCHUSER @USERS = @myUserTable, @FirstName = '';
GO
```